# Listing peer (desktop) directory structure on android device on same wifi Network

Tags: android, android-wifi, file-sharing

I am working on concept of sharing file between peer to peer. I have one desktop and Android connected to same **wifi network**. Using many application we can show file structure of android on desktop (i.e Airdriod without running scripting on desktop). But my issue is just to create opposite. I want to show file structure of Desktop at android side so that user can copy element directly to one's Android phone.

Comment: Instead of down-vote, please consider reason to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i met with **SMB file** sharing system and able to browse directory of Peer computer through my android application. This also help in creating peer to peer communication. Thanks goes to tutorial  [sambha file sharing](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sambha-jsifs-file-sharing.html)